# Trying to remove ROW from table but removes all my rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to remove a row based on my laravel IF condition. So if my field is not empty, then I want it to delete that row. However, when the script runs it keeps deleting all the rows from my page and not just those that are NOT empty. Could somebody potentially from my code, identify where my issue lays? I've haven't included a thorough background on my problem because I believe it's simply an issue with my forloop or placement of the code? However reason I've put it in my foreach loop is so that I can access the "t->section" attribute.

I've tried adding a data attribute so that it targets only the specific column and not all of them. Also I want this to happen as soon as the user visits the page so therefore no buttons or 'on' clicks were required.

```
@foreach($displayTickets as $t)
                        <tr class="hide" data-id="{{$t->id}}">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-ticket" style="font-size: 16px" aria-hidden="true"></i><a
                                        href="/ticket/{{ $t->slug }}"
                                        class="subject-link">{{ $t->title }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ $t->author }} {{$t->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $t->subject_area }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $t->created_at }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $t->reply_count }}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if($t->status == 'Open')
                                    <span class="status-green">{{ $t->status }}</span>
                                @elseif($t->status == 'Closed')
                                    <span class="status-red">{{ $t->status }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            @if(!empty($t->section))
                                    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                                        $('.hide').filter(function(){
                                           return $(this).data('id')
                                        }).remove();
                                    });
                                @endif    
                            </script>
                        @endforeach
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: I think `$(this).data('id')` is not returning a boolean value, so filter function doesn't work properly, can you tell me what is it returning?

Comment: Hm at the moment seems to be reporting "this.data is not a function" after me trying to console.log the error.

Comment: `$(this).data('id')` will return whatever value that data field has.  So, so long as that field is truthy, it's going to remove all fields that that is truthy for.

Comment: add `console.log($(this).data('id'))` before the return inside filter function to see

Comment: It also doesn't make sense for that script, in its current form, to be inside the for loop.  It's going to do the same exact logic for each loop.

Comment: @Luis it still returns the same error

Comment: @Taplar, yh I could take it outside the loop so that it may then work but I need to access that $t->section property which I can't do without the loop? maybe return it as a different collection in my controller?. Or did you mean the data id will remain the same and conduct that logic which I see now would make no sense.. I'm just trying to get the if condition to work by only removing rows its meant to.

Comment: Use your $t->section empty condition to add a class  server side and work that class into one script outside the loop. Or don't render them server side would make more sense

Comment: @charlietfl mind elaborating on what you mean adding the condition server side?

Comment: Well you are telling javascript to do some removal of elements as soon as the browser gets the page....so why render them server side at all? Just extra needless work by browser as it loads your page

Comment: Should be able to filter then out of data sent to view template even

Comment: Yeah true I understand you. Only reason was because I was having troubles with Archiving and SoftDeletes in Laravel so my only way was to just hide the elements when user views the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need those rows and they are not use on the rest of the page you can filter tickets one step earlier in your controller with where clause:

```
$displayTickets = Ticket::latest()->where('section',null)->get()
```

if you need them and just need to hide them in datatable:

```
<table>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($displayTickets as $t)
                    @if(empty($t->section))
                    <tr class="hide" data-id="{{$t->id}}">
                        <td><i class="fa fa-ticket" style="font-size: 16px" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="/ticket/{{ $t->slug }}" class="subject-link">{{ $t->title }}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $t->author }} {{$t->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $t->subject_area }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $t->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $t->reply_count }}</td>
                        <td>
                        @if($t->status == 'Open')
                            <span class="status-green">{{ $t->status }}</span>
                        @elseif($t->status == 'Closed')
                            <span class="status-red">{{ $t->status }}</span>
                        @endif
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     @endif
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Okay I could do that, only problem is I basically want to hide the contents of the page based on if the selected ticket has been archived or not.

Comment: @mohammed Hosseini Why I didn't think of filtering by the controller baffles me.... thank you very very much very simple fix!